# Bug: ASP.NET is interpreted as a link and hidden in my careers message

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I got a message from careers.stackoverflow.com that I have not yet indicated interest in, so the links are hidden.  But ASP.NET is being interpreted as a link!

My received text:

> ...seeking a passionate <link temporarily hidden> Software Engineer...

Comment: That's funny. I saw the same thing, I just thought they were being coy as to what programming language it was so I'd click 'I'm interested'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but how do you *know* it's ASP.NET? Maybe it's [zombo.com](http://www.zombo.com/)!

I just added the assumption that domain names in URLs must be at least 4 characters. Although there are 3-letter domain names out there..