# Is it worth hiding links?

Tags: discussion, jobs

When an employer is interested in you they get to send you a Careers Message asking if you are interested in them. If they send any email addresses or links (or even if they just type [ASP.NET](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31907/bug-asp-net-is-interpreted-as-a-link-and-hidden-in-my-careers-message)) it all gets hidden.

Is it really worth doing this? Can't an employer just say "Hey google my company name to find our site."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the initial employer message, we suppress …

- phone numbers
- email addresses
- URLs

… and the employers are informed of this in the help text next to the compose box.

Why do we do this? Because we need the *initial* contact to come through SOC, so we can measure the effectiveness of the employers and the CVs. If they bypass our initial contect UI, we cannot provide to employers or CV owners data on what's working and what isn't.

Note that we're *not* trying to inveigle ourselves into the whole process; we **quite happily get out of the way as soon as the first (positive) contact is made**.

Comment: fair point, but perhaps its worth making clear that the hidden bits are only emails/URLs - it was not clear to slow old me.  Especially as I showed interest just to see the hidden text to make sure I had not missed anything before I rejected the inquiry.  Also the employer URL was visible anyway... Thanks