# Careers message flow, why need to show interest in order to see full message

Tags: support, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth hiding links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31912/is-it-worth-hiding-links)

Hi,

I have read around the messages thing but still dont see why I need to show interest to see the complete message, why not just show the full message and then I can decide if I am interested.

Just had a message that I thought I was probably not interested in, but as there were hidden items, I decided to click on the interest/show full message link.  This added nothing of importance to affect my view, so I now want to respond "no interest"...

Obviously I can convey this to the company when they contact me, but it would save time for all concerned.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Agreed - duplicate, see link above.